# Add full size banner

Tags: blocks

In the two column layout on the category page the banner is contained in the right column alongside the left column filter. What is the best practice to position that banner above the 2 columns so that it is at a 100% width?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You cannot achieve it directly. It is sure from your question that, the block that renders the banner section resides inside `content` block. Your content block uses 2 column layout.

So the solution for this basically involves three steps.

*1. Remove the current banner block from layout*.

For that you can use this code

```
 <remove name="banner_block_name" />
```

*2. Define a structural block just above the content section* .

In this particular case, it should come in between breadcrumbs and content section.

*3. Insert banner block inside new structural block.*

***[Follow this post in detail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25941693/display-category-image-above-2-columns-layout-page-magento-ver-1-9-0-1/25947228#25947228)***. Here I am clearly explains above steps in detail. Instead of media block, you have to use banner block. That is the only difference. Feel free to ask if you have any doubts.

Answer (score 0):

I guess ,you is managed banner from view.phtml file(template/catalog/category).
If you want to manager banner above this then  you need to call your banner file after

by using 
below code at

```
<catalog_category_default>
<reference="root">
<block type="blockprefix/yourblocck" name="youblvok" as="youblvok" after="breadcrumbs"/>
</catalog_category_default>
<catalog_category_layered>
<reference="root">
<block type="blockprefix/yourblocck" name="youblvok" as="youblvok" after="breadcrumbs"/>
</catalog_category_layered>
```

at local.xml file

Comment: Amit, I don't think this code work. Because `root` block is will not render its child blocks automatcally. It uses `getChildHtml('child_block_name')` method to "position" all of its child block. `before` and `after` keywords only works when child blocks get automatically rendered. This happens only in two cases. either the parent block of type `core/text_list` or a parent block that render its child block with this single statement `getChildHtml()`.